# What streams to choose and where to place them correctly for processing url-addresses, receiving these images data and displaying them in a tableview?

Tags: json, swift, tableview, grand-central-dispatch, getimagedata

The situation is simple and very common. But unfortunately, for a specific situation, the answer is impossible to find on the Internet.
**Hi guys, please help!**
There is a function that receives a model data and also URL data, processes and store this data to array [interviewDataResponse]:

```
private func getInterviewResults() {
    guard let url = URL(string: self.interviewURL) else {
        debugPrint("URL is nil!")
        return
    }
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, _, error) in
        if data != nil, error == nil {
            do {
                let result = try JSONDecoder().decode([InterviewModel].self, from: data!)
                self.interviewDataResponse = Array(result.reversed())
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            } catch let error {
                debugPrint(error)
            }
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

Further:

As you can see in the following code, the getInterviewResults() function receives a data and subsequently processes additional data in custom cell, in cellConfigure() method to get this data for an images. The data is then displayed in the tableView with call method cellConfigure(). The actual data comes in, but not all images are displayed in the tableview.

```
public func cellConfigure(interview: [InterviewModel], for indexPath: IndexPath) {
    
    dateLabel.text = String((interview[indexPath.row].date)!.dropLast(6))
    tagsLabel.text = (interview[indexPath.row].tags).joined(separator: " #")
    titleTextView.text = interview[indexPath.row].title
    
    let webAddressURL = WebAddressURL.url
    guard let url = URL(
        string: webAddressURL + (interview[indexPath.row].picture!)) else {
            return
    }
    DispatchQueue.global().async {
        if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.photoImageView.image = UIImage(data: data)
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

In this case, the data is processed, but not all pictures are displayed in the tables.

Comment: Stop loading data form a remote URL with synchronous `Data(contentsOf`. And don't load data in the cell anyway. A cell can be deallocated immediately. Use a logic to load the images separately in the **controller** or **model** and cache them.

Answer (score 0):

CODE IN CUSTOM CELL:

```
public func cellConfigure(interview: [InterviewModel], for indexPath: IndexPath) {
    
    dateLabel.text = String((interview[indexPath.row].date)!.dropLast(6))
    tagsLabel.text = (interview[indexPath.row].tags).joined(separator: " #")
    titleTextView.text = interview[indexPath.row].title
    
    let webAddressURL = WebAddressURL.url
    guard let url = URL(
        string: webAddressURL + (interview[indexPath.row].picture!)) else {
            return
    }
    DispatchQueue.global().async {
        if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.photoImageView.image = UIImage(data: data)
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

CODE IN CLASS:

```
private func getInterviewResults() {
    guard let url = URL(string: InterviewURL.url) else {
        debugPrint("URL is nil!")
        return
    }
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, _, error) in
        if data != nil, error == nil {
            do {
                let result = try JSONDecoder().decode([InterviewModel].self, from: data!)
                self.interviewDataResponse = Array(result.reversed())
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            } catch let error {
                debugPrint(error)
            }
        }
    }.resume()
}
```